# Permanent (keep-alive) connection to TCPServer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, keep-alive, tcpserver

```
@server = TCPServer.new('', 2001)
Thread.new do
  loop do
    puts 'loop iteration'
    Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
      puts 'in thread'
      client.puts Time.now
      puts client.read
      client.close #This is the line I don't like
    end
  end
end
```

How to prevent connection closing and accept data from client without reconnects?

If I comment `client.close` out the server executes contents in thread only once, immediately after client connects and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Can u also post your client code?

I suppose this is happening because you just read only one message from the client till the end with `client.read` and than not doing any other reads on this connections. 
If you close it, your client might be just reconnection and then new TCPSocket is created by the TCPServer.

If you are not accepting the client to send any more messages immidiatly, it's perfectly fine to close the connection.

This is what an AcceptSocket (TCPServer) is for. It allows you to save ressources, by not 
having a running Thread to do polling for incoming messages.

If you do expect the client to send more messages in relativly short periods you should also have a loop in you Thread which is listening on a TCPSocket.

```
Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
  puts 'in thread'
  client.puts Time.now
  loop do
    puts client.gets #or client.read
  end
end
```

See also [ruby-tcp-chat](http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-tcp-chat/) Server#listen_user_messages

But then i guess you will need some timeout mechanism, which closes the connection if there have been no messages for some period of time, otherwise you end up with a lot of permanent running threads

Comment: I use debugging client named "Hercules setup utility".